# Converting HTML with ordered list and div with itextpdf

Tags: html-lists, itext, itextpdf

I tried to convert a HTML page with ordered list and some div tags with itextpdf, but it does not seem to work. I created the following simple ordered list structure in HTML to demonstrate the problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--  <div> -->
  <ol>
    <li>A
      <ol>
        <li>AA</li>
        <li>AB</li>
        <li>AC
          <ul>
            <li>ACA</li>
            <li>ACB</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>AD
          <ul>
            <li>ADA</li>
            <li>ADB</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <!--  </div> -->
</body>

</html>
```

It works fine so far, and I get the correct, well formatted PDF. When, however, I remove the comment around the div tag, it does not work any more. I get all element of the ordered list in a single line, in the result PDF file like this:

1. A AAABAC ACAACBAD ADAADB

My method for the conversion looks like this:

```
    private void convertHtmlToPdf(String htmlFilePath, String generatedPdfFilePath) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {
    String fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(htmlFilePath));

    OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File(generatedPdfFilePath));
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
    document.open();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent.getBytes());
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
    document.close();
    file.close();
}
```

So it is the simplest conversion code. I don't use any CSS, or insert any pictures. In my real code however, I do need to use CSS for the conversion, and the formatting is defined via div elements. So I can not simple remove all the div-s to get the conversion working.

Is it a bug, in itextpdf, or I miss something? Has anybody any idea for a workaround, to deal with this problem?

I am using the actually latest (5.5.6) version of itextpdf.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>

    <body>
     <div>
      <ol>
        <li>A
          <ol>
            <li>AA</li>
            <li>AB</li>
            <li>AC
              <ul>
                <li>ACA</li>
                <li>ACB</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>AD
              <ul>
                <li>ADA</li>
                <li>ADB</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ol>
     </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

this code should be work try it

Comment: Hi Kumar, no, unfortunately it does not work. You have just removed the comment around the div tag (as I wrote in the original problem description). Actually this is the point. The ordered list seems not to be working together with div in the itextpdf conversion.